# Render/redirect to a different view from a filter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I want to create a filter that is used in a Spring Boot (3.x) application. This filter should load another Spring MVC view if a certain header is sent in the request. The view that I want to load requires a "model map" attribute for it to render correctly. Here's an example:

```java
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isHeaderPresent = request.getHeader("SomeHeader") != null;        
        if (isHeaderPresent) {
            // Here, I'd like to access "ModelMap" to add an attribute like this:
            // modelMap.put("somekey", "somevalue");
            // Then I want to return the Thyeleaf "view" called "someview".
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. I want a filter that essentially does this for every controller (that the filter intercepts):

```java
@GetMapping("/something")
public String somewhere(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isHeaderPresent = request.getHeader("SomeHeader") != null;        
    if (isHeaderPresent) {
        modelMap.put("somekey", "somevalue");
        return "someview";
    } else {
        return "something";
    }
}
```

Note that I'm fine with *not* using a `Filter` if there's a better way to achieve it.

How can I achieve this?